# Изменение иконок маркеров по условию

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

Есть цикл добавления маркеров из базы:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
{
    LatLng lat = new LatLng(cursor.getDouble(1), cursor.getDouble(2));
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
              .position(lat)
              .title(cursor.getString(0)));
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при определенном имени изменялась иконка маркера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед добавлением маркера, проверяйте имя и при определенном имени меняйте иконку. Хотя не рекомендую такой подход, если имя не уникальное, лучше завести отдельное поле для индикации маркера, тип какой нибудь)

```
if (cursor.getString(0).equals("need_name")){
   your_bitmap = bitmap;
} 

Marker mapMarker= mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(lat)
                        .title(cursor.getString(0))
                        .icon(your_bitmap));
```

Answer (score 0):

У маркера есть [специальный метод](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#icon(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor)) для установки иконки.
У GoogleMap нету метода, возвращающего все маркеры. Это значит, что вам придется хранить их в массиве у себя (добавлять маркер в массив при добавлении на карту) примерно так:

```
List<MarkerOptions> markers = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();


...


MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(lat).title(cursor.getString(0));
markers.add(markerOptions);
mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

А когда надо изменить иконку - проходитесь по этому массиву, и вызываете вышеприведенный [метод](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#icon(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor))

Comment: Вот так меняется иконка для всех маркеров

Comment: for (int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
            {
                LatLng lat=new LatLng(cursor.getDouble(1),cursor.getDouble(2));
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(lat)
                                .title(cursor.getString(0))
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.i42))

                );
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

Comment: извините, не знаю как отформатировать код, чтобы наглядно было

Comment: @fc_barcelona, зачем вы мне написали то же, что и я вам? Так вы не меняете у маркеров иконки, а просто добавляете маркеры с другими иконками.